# How to open an old Word file (.doc) that is 3GB in size?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have found an old Word file (.doc), that contains a book I would like to recover. But the file is 3 GB in size, and both LibreOffice and Google Docs can't handle it - they crush in the process (Google could not even upload it and convert it).

What can I do? I don't have a licensed MS Word, but I assume it will be the same problem with it.

Comment: Have you tried `wordpad`? You might get lucky.

Comment: Some free alternatives : [AbleWord](http://www.ableword.net/index.html), [TextMaker](https://www.softmaker.com/en/softmaker-office-textmaker), [WPS Writer](https://www.wps.com/office/writer/?irclickid=3IPwAcQDaxyNU4y31%3AQo50iKUkAVmPQpnSDDxU0&irgwc=1&MediaId=30557&SharedId=&utm_source=impact&utm_medium=impact). One of them might manage to work with this document.

Comment: *Precisely* what OS are you running? How much RAM do you have? How much free drive space for swap?

Comment: Likely connected to RAM, yeah. One more alternative is to use some kind of converter to e.g. PDF, then optimize that, if you can find tools that do it progressively and accept large files. I know Ghostscript can handle large PDFs, for instance.

Comment: Do you have access to the full Word program at a library or other public institution? The limit on the size of a .doc file is about 32Mb *excluding images*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation 3Gb is a huge file, though, for the time period when Word used .doc files (1995-2006). Other programs also produced .doc files.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I tried WordPad, it opens the file (that's why I am pretty sure it's DOC), but the whole formatting in broken - most lines are 1 character long.

Comment: @Tetsujin Windows 11, 16 GB Ram, 16 GB for swap

Comment: Due to the size, only a 64-bit Word processor would support the file size.  Which is the reason Google Docs doesn't work. [Microsoft offers a free month to Office 365](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/try). Skip the hacks, start the trial, and then immediately cancel the trial, after you convert the document to a format you can read without Office.

Comment: You say you have the regular Word and that you haven't tried it. Please try it.

Comment: @music2myear no, I don't have a regular Word, where did I say that I do?

Comment: Apologies, I misread.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is verify that the file actually is a Word .DOC file and not some other kind of file. Any file can be renamed to have a different extension, so it's possible it could be something else, like an archive, a DOCX file, or even a multimedia file of some sort.

If it's really an MS Word DOC file, then the file should begin with a known sequence of bytes. Old MS DOC files usually begin with the hex values D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1. Viewing the first bytes of the file with a hex editor or hex dump tool can help determine what kind of file it is.

If it is a Word DOC file, it's very likely to be corrupted. A 3GB Word .DOC file is way larger than the format was designed to hold .DOC files can only contain a few dozen megabytes of text, so in order to get that large, the file would have to contain some enormous graphics or other embedded content. Even then it's still way bigger than the largest size a .DOC file should be.

If the file actually is a Word DOC file, contains what you think it does, your best option will be to try to open it with a program that only retrieves the text part of the file and ignores other content. One possibility is [Antiword, an old command line tool for extracting just the text from Word documents](http://web.archive.org/web/20060713151145/http://www.winfield.demon.nl/). It's quite old, and will require some fiddling to get it running on a modern Windows computer, but I believe it can be run on Linux.

If you can examine the beginning of the file with a hex editor or dump tool that can help determine what kind of file it actually is. If the file isn't really a .DOC file, then the next step is to figure out what kind of file it really is. There's a [list of common file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) on Wikipedia.

Comment: [TrID](https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) can identify file types based on contents. IIRC old .doc files were small filesystem-like containers, so it should be possible to extract just the embedded resources with a right tool

Comment: @gronostaj the file seems to large for it, it says `* Error: found no file(s) to analyze!`

Comment: @barbecue Thanks for the elaborate answer. I can't open the file in a plain text editor with hex support - it's too large for that. However, I can open it in WordPad (although with some crazy formatting like 1 character in each line), so I am quite confident it's really a Word file. It probably has a lot of images inside it.

Antiword seems to be a Linux-only program, I can't run in on Windows. I will try to search for similar Windows programs, thank you for the hint!

Comment: If must be you can run it in a Linux live session, no need to install anything (but you can if you want, either a dual-boot or a virtual machine)

Comment: But there is a Windows version. It seems you didn't read the link. It's right here: http://web.archive.org/web/20060720202927/http://www.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~markus/antiword/

Comment: Some hex and text editors allow you to open extremely large files by reading the file directly from disk rather than loading it into memory. This bypasses most file size limitations. WinHex is one option, and the UltraEdit text editor has this capability and can also display hexadecimal. It's not cheap, but a free trial version is available.